# Is there any way to do dry run a smart contract on Ethereum Mainnet?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, openethereum

For testing my codes without side effects (e.g., consuming gas, etc.) on the development environment, I'm finding a way to execute a smart contract that interacts with other contracts deployed on Ethereum Mainnet. Is there any way to do dry run contracts in the same state on mainnet?

---

Finally, **"[ganache-cli](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) --fork"** did this job. Thank you for an answer and a comment.

```
$ ganache-cli --fork http://localhost:8545@1599200

  -f, --fork                Fork from another currently running Ethereum client at a given block. Input should be
                            the HTTP location and port of the other client, e.g. 'http://localhost:8545' or
                            optionally provide a block number 'http://localhost:8545@1599200'
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@samajammin/how-to-interact-with-ethereums-mainnet-in-a-development-environment-with-ganache-3d8649df0876

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can run your own node and synchronize it fully. After that you can import the blockchain data to a local blockchain (Ganache) and use that. Then you can simulate transactions against the snapshot.

Of course this is only a snapshot and you either have to keep re-importing the latest mainnet snapshot or just use a slowly decaying snapshot.